# when i add 2 hours in gmdate it will zero minutes in Php

Tags: php

`$today = gmdate("M-j-Y-H-i");
 $date = gmdate('M-j-Y-H-i', strtotime($today . ' + 3 hours'));
 echo $today ."<br/>";
 echo $date;`

and its result

`Feb-24-2014-11-29
Feb-24-2014-14-00`

it will add 3 hours but it also set Minutes is zero i want to add only 3 hours in current GMT time

Comment: above code working fine in phpfiddle.http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/56u-b8k

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because you are using `$today` variable to make + 3 hours, simply remove that and you are ready to go

```
$today = gmdate("M-j-Y-H-i"); 
$date = gmdate('M-j-Y-H-i', strtotime('+ 3 hours'));
echo $today ."\n"; 
echo $date;
//output Feb-24-2014-12-18
//       Feb-24-2014-15-18
```

[**Live Sample Here**](http://codepad.org/GhqJQw95)

Comment: nvm, you where faster :)

Answer (score 0):

Those who are interested in a simpler version

```
$gmdate = gmdate(DATE_ATOM);
$loc_time = gmdate(DATE_ATOM, strtotime('+ 3 hours'));
```

[DATA_ATOM](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_gmdate.asp) and other formats which is basically same format used by MySQL `2018-10-28 13:14:18`